# Is migrating questions the right thing to do?

Tags: discussion

As a moderator on Travel Stack Exchange I do come across a lot of questions which we, the community on Travel, think fit better on Expatriates.
Most of the time I just close it with a 'move to an other Stack Exchange site' option.

Do you on Expatriates agree with that or would you like to see a bit more explanation as a comment on the moved questions? And do you think the people who asked the questions in the first place are understanding the moves?

Comment: While the mod has answered this question, I'd like to add [what CMs recommended on migration](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4138/2516) (after [Shog's revision](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4138/revisions)): "***Leave a comment** suggesting the asker re-post their question on [migration target] (and delete the one they posted here).*"

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I missed that bit of instruction.

Answer (score 2):

A a moderator, we can easily see what questions have been migrated to us from travel and what happens to them. There have been 33 migrations from travel to expats over the last 90 days. Of those, 9% were rejected (closed here and sent back to travel). Of the remaining questions, most have a couple of up votes and none have net negative scores.

Overall, I say you and the other travel mods are doing a good job of choosing what to migrate over. I would say there is no need to provide any comments.

As for what to tell users, I forget how the pinging works on a migrated question. It is probably best to tell a new user something.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should keep my habit of providing a few words of explanation of the move, and not get lazy and hasty.

Comment: "As for what to tell users, I forget how the pinging works on a migrated question. It is probably best to tell a new user something." -> the user receives a notification whenever one of their questions is migrated.